# Vaadin TextArea outdated

Tags: java, vaadin

I receive from the TextArea always the same value after event trigger, If I change the value before pushing the send Button it’s working correctly, after pushing the Button it stuck on the last value I’ve set.

VaadinUI:

```
    @Override
    public void init(VaadinRequest request) {
…
// build json mock data layout structure and connect field to processo            jsonRequestTextArea.setValue(mockJsonData);
    HorizontalLayout mainLayout = new HorizontalLayout(jsonRequestTextArea, actions);
    processor.setJsonRequesttextArea(jsonRequestTextArea);
      // add listener for process button
      sendRequestButton.addClickListener(e -> processor.processRequest());

}
```

Processor:

```
public void processRequest() {

    …

    // set json content paramenter
    parametersMap.add(":contentFile", jsonRequesttextArea.getValue());
  }
```

I followed the example found on this [Site](https://spring.io/guides/gs/crud-with-vaadin/)
Code can be clone from git:

```
git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-crud-with-vaadin.git
```

Is there a way to always get the last updated text from the TextArea?

Comment: Can you add a bit more code so that it is possible to compile/test? What version of Vaadin are you using?

Comment: Provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And specify version of Vaadin.

Comment: I just made some small changes on the original code, adding a setter on the processor for the TextFields and TextArea, which are being initialized at application start

Comment: Your line `processor.setJsonRequesttextArea(jsonRequestTextArea);` makes me wonder if you are accessing the TextArea from another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No problem

I see no problem when getting the `TextArea` object’s current contents by calling "getValue".

Here is an entire example app in Vaadin 8.3.0. Each time the button is clicked, the contents of the TextArea is prepended with the text ":contentFile" plus the current date-time in UTC. So each click is getting the value, and setting a new value; works each time without issue.

```
package com.basilbourque;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.*;

import java.time.Instant;

/**
 * Testing retrieval of contents from a TextArea.
 * <p>
 * See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48447476/642706
 * <p>
 * By Basil Bourque.
 */
@Theme ( "mytheme" )
public class MyUI extends UI
{
    static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;

    @Override
    protected void init ( VaadinRequest vaadinRequest )
    {
        // Init layout.
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setHeight( 100 , Unit.PERCENTAGE );

        // Widgets
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea( "TextArea" );
        textArea.setWidth( 100F , Unit.PERCENTAGE );
        textArea.setHeight( 100F , Unit.PERCENTAGE );
        String mode = textArea.getValueChangeMode().toString();  // `ValueChangeMode` enum. https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.3/8.3.0/docs/api/com/vaadin/shared/ui/ValueChangeMode.html
        textArea.setValue( "ValueChangeMode: " + mode );

        Button processButton = new Button( "Process" );
        processButton.addClickListener( clickEvent ->
        {
            String x = ":contentFile=" + Instant.now() + "\n" + textArea.getValue();
            textArea.setValue( x );
            textArea.setCursorPosition( 0 ); // Move insertion-point to top of the field for easy data-entry.
        } );

        // Arrange layout.
        layout.addComponents( textArea , processButton );
        setContent( layout );
    }

    @WebServlet ( urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true )
    @VaadinServletConfiguration ( ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false )
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet
    {
        static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot of example app]

## Conjecture

Your Question is not clearly written, and lacks sufficient detail & info. But it seems like you are seeing delays in perceiving value changes to a `TextArea`.

I suspect you may be accessing the value of the `TextArea` from another threads.

If so, you must keep in mind that there may be a delay between (a) the user typing text as data-entry in the web browser client-side, and (b) that typed text arriving server-side to be stored in the state of the actual widget.

Your Vaadin app really lives on the server in Java, with it UI remotely rendered automagically by the Vaadin framework client-side in the web browser using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc. That client-side framework accepts the user’s typing and passes it automatically back to the server-side for storage in a Java object (the `TextArea` instance).

But how often is that server-side object updated with the user’s typing? How much of a delay is involved? That depends on the [`ValueChangeMode`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.3/8.3.0/docs/api/com/vaadin/shared/ui/ValueChangeMode.html)  you specify with the methods [`TextArea::setValueChangeMode`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.3/8.3.0/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractTextField.html#setValueChangeMode--) and [`TextArea::getValueChangeMode`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.3/8.3.0/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractTextField.html#getValueChangeMode--). The constants `BLUR`, `EAGER`, [`LAZY`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.3/8.3.0/docs/api/com/vaadin/shared/ui/ValueChangeMode.html#LAZY), and `TIMEOUT` each prescribe a different timing. The default is `LAZY`, documented as:

> On every user event, schedule a server-side event after a defined interval, cancelling the currently-scheduled event if any. This is a good choice if you want to, for instance, wait for a small break in the user's typing before sending the event.

To speed up the delivery of user input to server-side, change the mode to `EAGER` to update nearly on every keystroke. But this will increase network traffic, making your app much more “chatty”. Not good with poor internet connections but perhaps fine on a local network.

To move the user input to server-side less frequently, choose `BLUR` to deliver input only after the keyboard focus leaves that field to move to another field or other widget.

So, when you access the `TextArea` instance’s current value, it may not actually be so current. While the user is typing, that fresh text may not yet have made the voyage across the network from browser-side HTML/JavaScript to server-side Java object.

By the way, if working with the `TextArea` from another thread, be sure you do so properly through the [`UI.access`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.3/8.3.0/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html#access-java.lang.Runnable-) and [`VaadinSession.access`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.3/8.3.0/docs/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinSession.html#access-java.lang.Runnable-) methods. Never directly access user-interface widgets from a background thread.

Comment: Thanks man, you are perfectly right, i was putting an extrmely long text in the TextArea and it Vaadin was not able to process it before pulling the trigger.